# Há um "em" a mais no texto do período da eleição

Tags: bug, tradução, localização, eleição

Prestem atenção na imagem abaixo:
[image: emem]

> <sup><sub>A eleição encerra-se</sub></sup> **em em** <sup><sub>3 dias.</sub></sup>

Tem um "**em**" a mais na frase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ao que parece, o bug foi corrigido. Neste momento está exibindo o seguinte:

> A eleição encerra-se em 12 horas.

Ontem eu vi aparecer isso:

> A eleição encerra-se em amanhã.

Mas depois estava isso:

> A eleição encerra-se amanhã.